# Shall I use mySQL to store value or format with function

Tags: php, mysql

I have a two separate tables that contain parts of user name (don't ask why)...

```
t1
---------------
firstName
lastName

t2
---------------
middleName
stage_firstName
stage_middleName
stage_lastName
```

So before I output the name I run it through a function that capitalizes First letter of Name and uses Stage name if provided.

It works OK, but I now have a case where I need to display multiple names. The question I have, is: shall I use mySQL to store properly formatted name when the user formats it initially, or keep the values in multiple tables and keep on using the function to format them. For some reason I think I can improve some performance by utilizing a single value from a table, even if I add additional table column rather than keeping the fields separately in two separate tables and then parsing each name through this huge function.

Am I wrong with these assumptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And if, at some point, you need to extract the name and display/use it in a different format, you will need to then perform some kind of translation on the already formatted string.

You could write the formatting into the query though.

Comment: If I need a different formatting I can pull different parts of the name again. But in general, I think adding one more column in order to store formatted string will help with speeding up things vs. pulling 4 different fields from 2 different tables and then putting them together with a function, right?

Comment: it's all a bit of a balance - you'd save on the reading and display, but incur a cost on writing and with storage.

Comment: True. Storage is just a few characters per cell and writing will be done at the moment the name is updated. Display, however will be done for multiple rows at once and from a number of rows and joined tables. I think I'm leaning towards adding an extra column. Thanks for the insight.